# How to programatically change the label of a datagrid column in livecode

Tags: livecode

I have 2 sets of data that I would like to display in the same grid. The number and size of column required are the same but I need to change the column headers. How do I do that programatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the "columns" property using the dgProps array:

```
set the dgProps["columns"] of control "DataGrid 1" to "col3" & cr & "col2" & cr & "col1"
```

For more datagrid property info, see this page: http://lessons.runrev.com/m/datagrid/l/7343-data-grid-properties

Comment: Scott this works but I noticed that the link you gave uses group instead of control `"put the dgProp[ PROPERTY_NAME ] of group "Data Grid"`. Are you able to clarify the difference